# Parse master key cloud code following users

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I'm building a simple social network app for iOS with parse and I'm currently working on the relationships, such as follower and following. I have follower and following column in my data browser saved as an array so I can save all the usernames. So this is what I'm having trouble with: Say the current user is viewing a user's profile and clicks follow I need to have the current user's name save in the follower array of the user he/she is viewing. Now as far as I know I can't o this on the client side, and it isn't a good idea anyway for security reasons to do ether. So I want to try to use the Master Key and cloud code to add each of the user's names to their appropriate array. I have never used cloud code before and I want to make sure that this is the best way to do this. I set up the Cloud Code I just don't know where to begin. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by creating a new function in main.js in your cloud code folder. Just insert the `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` part at the beginning. I would send up the object id of the user you are modifying, then in the function grab the array from that user, and add the current user to it. Then save and send back a success variable.

To call this from Xcode you would have something like this:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"editFollowers" withParameters:@{@"user": Put objectId for user here}                             
block:^(NSString *response, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {

                                    }
                                }];
```

Comment: I'm still confused what to do on the cloud code side.

Comment: @Jack you mean writing the actual cloud code function?

Comment: I would read the parse docs on cloud code and JavaScript. If you know how to write the code you need in obj c, then just read the JavaScript docs and create a cloud code function with that code in JavaScript.